# On the definition of "dynamic type" for glvalues

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, definition

From [defns.dynamic.type]:

> **dynamic type**
> <glvalue> type of the most derived object [intro.object] to which the glvalue refers
> [*Example*: If a pointer [dcl.ptr] `p` whose static type is “pointer to class B” is pointing to an object of class D, derived from B [class.derived], the dynamic type of the expression `*p` is “D”. References [dcl.ref] are treated similarly. —*end example*]

Consider the following (based on the example given above):

```
class B {};
class D: public B {} d;
B *p = &d; // dynamic type of `*p`?
```

It seems according to the purport of the example that the dynamic type of `*p` would be "`D`". However, [dcl.init] stipulates that the initializer prvalue `&d` will be converted (by standard pointer conversion) to "pointer to `B`" before becoming the initial value of `p`. Per [conv.ptr], that value will be "a pointer to the base class subobject of the derived class object" (that is, the `B` subobject of `d`). Then per [expr.unary.op], `*p` will be an lvalue referring to the `B` subobject, not a most derived object, never mind `d`. What then is its dynamic type? Furthermore, how could `p` ever actually point to `d` without a `reinterpret_cast<B*>`?

Comment: The definition should say smth like «type of the most derived object **of the object** to which the glvalue refers» and I remember there was an editorial issue saying this, but couldn't find it.

Comment: I agree, but then there's [CWG #2051](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1359r0.html#2051): According to this, if I tried to access the `B` subobject through `*p`, it'd be UB.

Comment: *p will be indeed an lvalue referring to the B subobject, that's true. Why is this a problem? That B subobject is a base-class subobject of a D object, so D would be its dynamic type.

Comment: "According to this, if I tried to access the B subobject through *p, it'd be UB" I don't see it written anywhere.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. The (static) type of the (g)lvalue `*p` is "B", which is not similar [conv.qual] to the dynamic type ("D") of the (sub)object to which it refers. Thus, the attempt to access is UB per [basic.lval]/11.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Re your first comment: The current definition of "dynamic type" calls for the "most derived object to which the glvalue refers". That's a problem because `*p` doesn't refer to a most derived object.

Comment: The intent is crystal clear. I am not interested in discussing the less-than-perfect wording.

Comment: There can't be access to an object of non-scalar type.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer True; I stand corrected (about 2051). There's even a note that I somehow managed to overlook at the end of the proposed wording.